# Multiple Hyperlink Styling in one css

Tags: css

I'm trying to accomplish having different hyperlink styling per div.  I have an overall hyperlink style and then a div that I want all hyperlinks in that div a completely different style.  I'm just not sure how to code the css.  Any help would be awesome.

```
a {color:#d85d5d; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {color:#222; text-decoration:underline;}

.SingleLink
{
    #a
    #a:{
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #a:link {
        color: #0000FF;
    }

    #a:visited {
        color: #660099;
    }

    #a:active {
        color #FF0000;
    }

    #a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

}
```

So basically everything in my page has the first a and then anything in the .SingleLink div has a different hyperlink styling.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use nested styles like in your post take a look at less or scss.

Comment: The answers below are correct. That being said, you're well on your way to learning how to write LESS or SASS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the class name for each, you can't wrap them like you have done in your example with pure CSS.

Using the code below should fix this:

```
.SingleLink a {  text-decoration: underline; }

.SingleLink a:link { color: #0000FF; }

.SingleLink a:visited { color: #660099; }

.SingleLink a:active { color #FF0000; }

.SingleLink a:hover { font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to specify the .SingleLink selector for each rule like so:

```
.SingleLink a:link { color: #0000FF; }

.SingleLink a:visited { color: #660099; }

.SingleLink a:active { color #FF0000; }

.SingleLink a:hover { font-weight: bold; }
```

Using {} to group rules under a selector is only valid syntax for some CSS preprocessors like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), but isn't valid as "pure" CSS.